# Running java from command line doesnt create new.txt

Tags: java, file, cmd

I made small java app that amongst other things has to write data to .txt file.
If file exists it should append text on the bottom but if there is no file it should create new one.

Code is working when i execute it inside Netbeans but it doesn't work when i execute it from command line (Windows 7).

This is the code i'm using:

```
Writer writer = null;

try {
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
          new FileOutputStream(doc+".txt",true), "utf-8"));
    writer.write("===============================================");
    writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
    writer.write("Results "+i+":");
    writer.append(System.lineSeparator());
    //few more text lines
    //..
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error.");
} finally {
   try {writer.close();} catch (Exception ex) {}
}
```

Command im executing (file path is 100% correct):

```
java -jar "C:\Users\restoffilepath.jar" 5 5 1 docname
```

Why it doesn't create a new document when running from cmd?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Displaying "Error" when an exception occurs is not helpful. Try to print at least the stack trace: `ex.printStackTrace()`

Comment: Is your class name `public static void main(String[] args0) { }`? Did you export the `.jar` file correctly?

Comment: Main class is public static void main(String[] args){} and i trust i did export it correctly.

Comment: Provide the command you actually typed at the command line to try and run it :)

Comment: What does the command line look like that you are running it?   Are you sure you are checking the correct directory for your file?

Comment: There's a fair chance that it is actually creating the file, but just not where you're expecting it to put it. The directory that you're running from might be different in NetBeans from the directory when you're running from the command line.

Comment: Are you running your command line in admin mode?

Comment: @chiastic-security, you were right. It actually did create document in another directory and for some strange reason file didn't appear in search right away (i did try to search for it right afterwards).

Since i did find answer should i post it or delete question?

Comment: @ower best thing is for me to convert my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It almost certainly *is* creating the file, if you're not getting an error reported. But the working directory from which NetBeans runs your program might not be the same as the working directory when you run it from the command line, so the file is likely to have ended up in a different directory from the one you're looking in.

(Answer converted from a comment: this was indeed the problem OP was having.)